# C# How to use a TransactionScope across multiple dynamically loaded AppDomain?

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions, appdomain, transactionscope

I want to perform activity in various SqlConnections across multiple dynamically created AppDomains.

Each AppDomain will be sequentially created & code dynamically invoked. Each AppDomain will create its own SqlConnection (using the same ConnectionString).

How can I have all activity performed under a single Transaction?

1) Can a TransactionScope handle this with the help of MSDTC?

2) Can I directly call the BEGIN/COMMIT/ROLLBACK TRANSACTION command, and somehow share a MSSQL Transaction between multiple db connections?

3) Any other options?